# Getting the next token and remaining String with StreamTokenizer

Tags: java

I have a StreamTokenizer that will tokenize a String. I am interested in a way to get the next token from a String, as well as the remaining String (without the token we just took).

```
public static void parseString(String s){
    StreamTokenizer st = new StreamTokenizer(new StringReader(s));

    try {
        while (st.nextToken() != st.TT_EOF){
            if (st.ttype == st.TT_WORD){
                System.out.println("Word: " + st.sval);
                if (st.sval.equals("start")){
                    start(st.sval, ???)
                }
            }
            else if (st.ttype == st.TT_NUMBER){
                System.out.println("Number: " + st.nval);

            }
            else if (st.ttype == '\''){
                System.out.println(st.sval);
            }
            else{
                System.out.println((char)st.ttype);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e){}
}



public String start(String text, String theRest){
    return "<start>" + text + "" + parseString(theRest) + "</start>";
}
```

Some things I've tried:

- I've tried just using the original String s but StreamTokenizer doesn't alter a String after it tokenizes it (I forget the word to describe this).
- I could find the index of the current token, and slice that token out of the original string.

I was wondering if there was a more elegant way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

In regards to the first bullet point, I believe the word you're thinking of is probably "immutable". You're correct, anything that seems to be manipulating a String is in fact creating a new string; the original is left intact.

For the second bullet point, frankly I would have suggested the same as well. At the moment I cannot think of a better way.

Here's a general example:

```
int startIndex = s.indexOf(currentToken) + currentToken.length;

String remainingString = s.subString(startIndex, s.length-1);
```

If my string is "Hi my name is Paul", and the current token is "name", the result of `remainingString` should be " is Paul".

You could easily encapsulate that in a helper method somewhere to help keep things clean and separated.

Probably not the answer you're looking for, but hopefully that somewhat helps.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I will work with the indexes and substrings until someone else suggests a more clever way.